# JMeter: JSON Extractor - Extract using multiple conditions

Tags: json, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter-5.0

I want to extract JSON block where it satisfies multiple conditions. For example, extract a block which has variables with two or more desired value. Please see below given example.

```
[
  {
   id:"1",
   name:"ABC",
   appName:"XYZ",
   state:"New",
   appType:"owner",
   date:"May 12"
  },

  {
   id:"2",
   name:"DEF",
   appName:"UVW",
   state:"In Progress",
   appType:"manager",
   date:"May 13"
  },

  {
   id:"3",
   name:"GHI",
   appName:"RST",
   state:"In Progress",
   appType:"owner",
   date:"May 12"
  }
]
```

From the above JSON, I want to extract the JSON block where state:"In Progress" and appType:"Owner"; i.e. the following block:

```
  {
   id:"3",
   name:"GHI",
   appName:"RST",
   state:"In Progress",
   appType:"owner",
   date:"May 12"
  }
```

I've been using JSON Extractor where I put JSON Path expressions:

`$.[?(@.state == "In Progress") && ?(@.appType== "owner")]`

But it doesn't extract any result. Is there any "AND/&&" condition to extract that particular block. Please help!

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$..[?(@.state=="In Progress" && @.appType=="owner")]
```

this will give you the desired block from array.

Comment: @Siddharth Gandhi  - did the solution worked for you !

Comment: Yes, it worked. I have a question, In complex queries what can I do if I want state as New or In progress and appType as owner. Can I do it like ((New || In Progress) && Owner) ?? Thanks in advance.